24.04 How to disable Super + left/right
I constantly hit the windows button and left/right, my windows get put into half of the screen. I can't find this keybinding combo (I think super + left/right) anywhere. I tried regular settings and I tried compiz settings manager (from here How can I reassign the semi-maximize keyboard shortcut?). Neither works.
How can I disable this?

Yes, sorry, I just had the 24.04 LTS update (after the first bugfix release) and I got confused with the release identifiers.

I am also desperately trying to disable this key combination without any success.
